# How to checked customer is login or Not using customer Id or email using REST API

Tags: magento2

How We can checked customer is login or not using Customer Data,

Comment: Checking customer login at rest api is not  good. What you want to implement Please explain

Comment: My 3rd party site want to checked is customer log in on magento site or not through API.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all REST API's which is available in Magento2 core code in the customer module. I didn't find any such ready made api or even any function which helps you directly.

This is because in general we don't require to validate any specific customer's session. We may need to require writing the business logic in case of any customer is logged in irrespective who the customer is.

However, I do find one solution through which you can achieve your requirements. You may follow the below steps. I hope you are little bit familiar with Magento2 webapi implementation. So I am not writing whole code in detail but I am just guiding you.

1. Create a custom module. In that create one webapi to check the specific customer is logged in or not.
2. You may refer below links to create a custom api endpoint.

- https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-custom-rest-api/
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

3. Pass the customer ID in webapi request that you have just created.
4. In the model function which is associated with your webapi, inject "**Magento\Customer\Model\Session**" class.
5. Now first use this method "**setCustomerId($id)**" method of above injected class. Pass the customer ID in this method which you have received from the api request argument.
6. Then use another function from the same injected class "**isLoggedIn()**". This function will return true if that customer is logged in or else it will return false. You may return this value in your webapi response and can check at frontend whether the specific customer is logged in or not of which customer ID you have passed in the api request.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Pratik I tried this solution and its always returning true even customer is logout in fromtend

Comment: If you set customer id properly before checking "isLoggedIn()" function then it should be working fine.. Can you please use this function "getCustomerId()" after logout and check whether it is returning the same customer id as yours or any other?